# Stopping a function running on a dedicated thread in python with switches

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, server, switch-statement

I have the following problem: Iam currently working on a function in my program where you can run a server socket on your computer so clients can connect to host a simple chat. You simply type in the port you want and then click on the switch to turn it on like this:

[image]

The server script runs fine on a seperate thread but i dont know how to stop the server again when turning the switch off.

## the server and switch code

```
import socket
import threading
from tkinter import *


def server_func(port):
    host = ""

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((host, int(port)))
    server.listen()

    client_list = []
    user_names = []

    def send_message(message):
        for client in client_list:
            client.send(message)

    def handle_messages(client):
        while True:
            try:
                message = client.recv(1024)
                send_message(message)
            except:
                index = client_list.index(client)
                client_list.remove(client)
                client.close()
                user_name = user_names[index]
                send_message("{} left!".format(user_name).encode("ascii"))
                user_names.remove(user_name)
                break

    def receive_messages():
        while True:
            client, address = server.accept()
            print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))

            client.send("NICK".encode("ascii"))
            user_name = client.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
            user_names.append(user_name)
            client_list.append(client)

            print("Username is {}.".format(user_name))
            send_message("{} joined.".format(user_name).encode("ascii"))
            client.send("Connected to server.".encode("ascii"))

            thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_messages, args= (client,))
            thread.start()

    receive_messages()


serv_window = Tk()
serv_window.resizable(0, 0)
serv_window.title("MyApp")

blank_net_font = Label(serv_window, text="MyApp", font="Arial 14 bold", width=30, 
pady=4, bg="grey")
blank_net_font.grid(row=0, column=0)

network_font = Label(serv_window, text="Network", font="Arial 12 bold", bg="light 
grey", width=36, pady=4)
network_font.grid(row=1, column=0)

network_window = LabelFrame(serv_window)
network_window.grid(row=2, column=0)

global is_on
is_on = True

server_label = Label(network_window, text="Server is OFF", font="Arial 12 bold", 
width=11)
server_label.grid(row=0, column=0)


def server_switch():
    global is_on
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server_func, args=(port_entry.get(),))
    if is_on:
        on_button.configure(image=on)
        server_label.configure(text="Server is ON")
        is_on = False
        server_thread.start()
    else:
        on_button.configure(image=off)
        server_label.configure(text="Server is OFF")
        is_on = True


port_label = Label(network_window, text="PORT", font="Arial 12 bold")
port_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

port_entry = Entry(network_window, font="Arial 12", width=6, bg="light grey")
port_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)

on = PhotoImage(file="on_switch.gif", master=serv_window)
off = PhotoImage(file="off_switch.gif", master=serv_window)

on_button = Button(network_window, image=off, bd=0, command=server_switch)
on_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

serv_window.mainloop()
```

## the client code

```
import socket
import threading

user_name = input("Choose your username: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("server_ip", port))


def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
            if message == "NICK":
                client.send(user_name.encode("ascii"))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("An error occurred")
            client.close()
            break


def write():
    while True:
        message = "{}: {}".format(user_name, input(""))
        client.send(message.encode("ascii"))


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

image of off switch
[image]

image of on switch
[image]

Comment: You could send a specific message to server when switching to off, at server You check messages and if message equals the specific combination break out of loop, make sure however that such message won't get sent from user (check each message user inputs before sending)

Comment: Also usually server, client and GUI are in separate files

Comment: Use a flag variable instead of `True` in the while loop inside `receive_messages()`, then change value of this flag to terminate the while loop.

Comment: You can also use a stoppable thread like [this one](https://github.com/TheLizzard/Bismuth-184/blob/b2bf81596292661d3eaec28b6984450301b82def/src/_terminal/stoppablethread.py) but I wouldn't recommend using it unless you absolutely have to